# Collection representation of a grid like bubble poke game in java

Tags: java, collections

I am creating a game, in which the player clicks on a gui component A and if there are components with the same color vertically and horizontally, remove them. the minime number of colors to remove is 2.
so in a grid like this: 
n is null,####

```
                    A B A C
                    A B C C
                    B C A A
                    C A B B
```

if the user clicks in C's of the top-left, the grid would look like this:####

```
                    A B n n
                    A B A n
                    B C A A
                    C A B B
```

Another example:####

A B A C
A B C C
B C A C
A B C C

And after click in any C of 4 and 3 columns:####

A B n n
A B n n
B C A n
A B A n

So my question, yet possible just opinion, but how would you represent this data structure in Java?
Is it linkedLists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I would just use a 2 dimensional ArrayList, or even a 2 dimensional array of the datatype you use for making up the grid. By using a 2-dimensional, navigating to neighbouring items is pretty straightforward:

Declaration:

```
T[width][height] grid;
// TODO: fill grid with items
```

Get Neighbouring cells (x is x-value of original cell, y is y-value of original cell):

```
// Top neigbour
grid[x][y-1];

// Bottom neighbour
grid[x][y+1];

// Left neighbour:
grid[x-1][y];

// Right neighbour:
grid[x+1][y];

// Etc for diagonal neighbours
```

Comment: I'd make a class called Grid<T> that has a 2d array under the hood. The Table class from Guava could also be an appropriate choice.

Comment: @Chill What is this Table class you are talking about that I do not know of? Is it this one? [https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained]

Comment: Yup. Javadocs are here https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.html.

Comment: It's probably overkill though. Writing your own is probably the best way in this case.

Comment: Indead, creating a wrapper class Grid<T> for T[][] is the right solution. It enables you to group all it's methods where they belong. It's the OO-way!